# Non-zero exit status in R Jupyter Notebook but not in R

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

I am receiving a non-zero exit status when trying to install ggpubr in my R Jupyter Notebook. I was having this same issue about 2 weeks ago when trying to install gglot2, which I kept fumbling around including changing the CRAN and the package eventually installed.

I think there may be an issue at installing the dependencies in Jupyter notebook. I went back to the previous notebook where I installed ggplot2 and tried to run that code to see whether ggplot2 would reinstall--it doesn't and now that also returns non-zero exit status. I don't understand why I was once able to eventually install ggplot2 and I no longer can and I cannot install ggpubr either.

Note I've been able to install both ggplot2 and ggpubr in R, so I think this may be a Jupyter Notebook issue. I am an absolute beginner with coding, so any help with this and advice is much appreciated!!

Using macOS Mojave 10.14.6

```
install.packages("ggpubr")

also installing the dependencies ‘nloptr’, ‘pbkrtest’, ‘lme4’, ‘car’, ‘rstatix’

Warning message in install.packages("ggpubr"): “installation of package ‘nloptr’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("ggpubr"): “installation of package ‘lme4’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("ggpubr"): “installation of package ‘pbkrtest’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("ggpubr"): “installation of package ‘car’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("ggpubr"): “installation of package ‘rstatix’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("ggpubr"): “installation of package ‘ggpubr’ had non-zero exit status”
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library' Making 'packages.html'

...done
```

Answer (score 1):

I kept getting the non-zero exit status when trying to install packages with Jupyter notebook with R kernel and was failing because of multiple dependencies when wanting to install a package. I am not an expert in any of these so please forgive me if I make an error in explaining or if it is a non-issue for you but please feel free to comment to clear things out. I just want to share my success story so hopefully it can help someone else:
I am working on a MacBook Pro. Here are the information I get when I run R.version() on my jupyter notebook with R kernel:

```
$platform           'x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu'
$arch               'x86_64'
$os                 'linux-gnu'
$system             'x86_64, linux-gnu'
$language           'R'
$version.string     'R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)'
```

These are the steps to take to fix the issue:

1. Go to https://anaconda.org/
2. Search the package name that you are trying to install
3. Copy the one line that is given to install the package, it should be something like:
   Conda install -c r r-caret
   #conda install -c r r-package_name
   NOTE: sometimes during installing packages, you’re asked whether or not you want to continue, so add --y at the end of the above statement to continue, so something like this
   Conda install -c r r-caret --y (I will always add it just to be on the safe side)
4. Click on the new launcher (+ icon) to create a new notebook with PySpark (once opened it has .ipynp extension)
5. On the first cell paste the copied line from step 3 and run
6. Once done, restart the kernel on the current notebook
7. Restart the kernel on your other notebook with R kernel
8. Run library (package_name) on your notebook with R kernel (e.x. library(caret))